# Why will the following run in parallel rather than sequentially?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

Given the following functions for `evalPair`, `parPair` and `deepSeq` respectively,

```
evalPair :: Strategy a -> Strategy b -> Strategy (a,b)
evalPair sa sb (a,b) = do
      a' <- sa a
      b' <- sb b
      return (a',b')

parPair :: Strategy a -> Strategy b -> Strategy (a,b)
parPair sa sb = evalPair (rparWith sa) (rparWith sb)

rdeepseq :: NFData a => Strategy a
rdeepseq x = rseq (force x)
```

The question is why will the following code be evaluated in parallel as the author claims?

```
parPair rdeepseq rdeepseq :: (NFData a, NFData b) => Strategy (a,b)
```

I am in dount since Simon Marlow says the following

> To break down what happens when this `Strategy` is applied to a pair:
>   `parPair` calls `evalPair`, and `evalPair` calls `rparWith rdeepseq` on each
>   component of the pair. So the effect is that each component will be
>   fully evaluated to normal form in parallel.

According to what I see `rparWith rdeepseq` is informally `rpar . rseq . force` which means the argument will be evaluated to normal form, which it will be evaluated with `rseq` sequentially, and hence in the end the `rpar` is of no use in a parallel context.

Everything is taken from Simon Marlow's book.

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look at `parPair rdeepseq rdeepseq`:

```
parPair rdeepseq rdeepseq (a,b)
 = evalPair (rparWith rdeepseq) (rparWith rdeepseq) (a,b)
 = do
    a' <- rparWith rdeepseq a
    b' <- rparWith rdeepseq b
    return (a', b')
```

Since `rparWith` sparks it arguments, `rdeepseq a` will be evaluated in parallel (possibly). It wouldn't be in parallel, if you were to use

```
evalPair rdeepseq rdeepseq
```

instead. The `rparWith` is essential, as it sparks its argument for evaluation with the given strategy.

Comment: So your answer would mean that my understanding of strategy composition was incorrect (i.e rparWith rdeepseq == rpar . rseq . force is basically incorrect)? 
BTW thanks for the answer.

Comment: @McGill: no, that's completely fine (well, except for the missing `dot`, since you cannot compose strategies with `(.)`) But `(.) f g x` is `f (g x)`, so `(rpar . rseq. force) x` is `rpar (rseq (force x))`. In other programming languages, we would have to evaluate `force x` to use `rseq`. But since Haskell isn't strict, we don't actually evaluate the arguments in `rpar <something>`. Instead, we hand `<something>` over to `rpar`, which _then_ sparks `<something>` for evaluation in parallel.