# Haskell: why following run sequentially?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

Good day. Given code

```
import           Control.DeepSeq
import           Control.Exception
import           Control.Parallel
import           Control.Parallel.Strategies
import           System.Environment
import           Text.Printf

l = [34,56,43,1234,456,765,345,4574,58,878,978,456,34,234,1234123,1234,12341234]
f x = Just (sum [1..x])

fun1 :: [Maybe Integer]
fun1 = map f l `using` parList rdeepseq
fun2 :: [Maybe Integer]
fun2 = map f l `using` evalList (rparWith rdeepseq)
fun3 :: [Maybe Integer]
fun3 = map f l `using` evalList (rpar . force)

main :: IO ()
main = print fun1
```

Why `fun1` and `fun2` run sequentially?
From what I understood, rparWith should spark its argument. Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41855707/3900540) states the same. But for fun1 and fun2 I'm getting output like "SPARKS: 0 (0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)". So Sparks were not even created.
`fun3` works as expected with sparks being created.
Ty for help

UPD: And I found that `rdeepseq` makes example from book (Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell) works in sequence. Book says:

> And we can use parPair to write a Strategy that fully evaluates both components of a pair in parallel:
>
> parPair rdeepseq rdeepseq :: (NFData a, NFData b) => Strategy (a,b)
>
> To break down what happens when this Strategy is applied to a pair: parPair calls, and evalPair calls rparWith rdeepseq on each component of the pair. So
>   the effect is that each component will be fully evaluated to normal form in parallel.

But if I run

```
(Just (fib 35), Just (fib 36)) `using` parPair rdeepseq rdeepseq
```

or even

```
(fib 35, fib 36) `using` parPair rdeepseq rdeepseq
```

Threadscope shows only one core running and 0 sparks created.

fib implemented like this (from book too)

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Comment: How are you compiling and running this?

Comment: You need to use the GHC option `-threaded` and run the executable with `+RTS -Nx` where `x` is the number of cores to use. Are you doing this in your testing?

Comment: Yes, compile with "ghc -O2 [filename.hs]  -threaded -rtsopts -eventlog". Then run with "[filename] +RTS -N2 -l"

Comment: Also `(Just (fib 35), Just (fib 36)) \`using\` evalPair (rparWith (rseq . force)) (rparWith (rseq . force))` shows 2 core busy, but `(Just (fib 35), Just (fib 36)) \`using\` parPair rdeepseq rdeepseq` only one. As far as I understood, those should be sort of equivalent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rparWith` was defined using `realWorld#`, a deeply magical GHC internal value. The way it was used is essentially the same as applying a "function" sometimes called `accursedUnutterablePerformIO` (more officially, `unsafeInlinePerformIO`). Using it is only legitimate when the `IO` in question is actually exceptionally pure. The thinking was that since `Eval` is just for calculation, that should be fine. But in fact, sparking threads is an `IO` effect, and one we care about! The optimizer was rearranging those effects in an unfortunate way, causing them ultimately to be dropped. The fix was to use `unsafeDupablePerformIO` instead. That's a much better-behaved "function", and seems to do the trick. See [the ticket](https://github.com/haskell/parallel/issues/17) for details.

Note: my initial fix turned out to be a bit wrong; it's now been modified once again.

Comment: Guess, this should be the answer

Answer (score 0):

The [original paper](https://simonmar.github.io/bib/papers/strategies.pdf) describes `rdeepseq` as

```
rdeepseq :: NFData a => Strategy a
rdeepseq x = rnf x ‘pseq‘ return x
```

And indeed, if you use this definition, it will create sparks, like you'd expect. Looks like `rdeepseq` sematrics was changes (probably [here](https://github.com/haskell/parallel/commit/e4f34d858cd330084abbc86e3e4dbe6727b43f06#diff-bfe9562b593bd5b0d5b0cf087ba38790L343)), intentionally or incidentally. I don't see any note neither in the documentation, nor in the changelog, so it is probably a bug. Please create at issue on their [bug tracker](https://github.com/haskell/parallel/issues) and ask maintainers for clarification.

Comment: Looks like this is some known issue, so I just commented here https://github.com/haskell/parallel/issues/17

Comment: The actual issue turned out to have nothing whatsoever to do with `rdeepseq` and everything to do with `rparWith`. See the ultimate ticket resolution.